# Can the same wildcard SSL be used for site1.mysite.com and site2.mysite.com when they are hosted on different servers IPs

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy

I have godaddy 5 subdomains certificate. Currently its used for site1.mysite.com. I have CNAME DNS record that directs site2.mysite.com to another server (on another HOST). can I use the certificate from Godaddy for site2.mysite.com? Or I have to buy another certificate for another IP address?

I have issued certificate request for site2.mysite.com from godaddy but it seems to not want new certificate data but just allows site2 with all the data I setup when registering mysite.com certificate.

Comment: do you have a wildcard certificate (*.mysite.com) or do you only have a certificate for site1.mysite.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got both halves of the certificate there's no *technical* reason why you can't install the SSL cert on multiple servers.

However doing so may be against the terms of sale of the SSL certificate, so check your contract.

My own previous experience is with Thawte / Verisign, whose standard pricing only allows you to install a certificate on a single server.  If you've got a load-balanced cluster they require you to purchase an additional "license" for each additional server in the cluster.

FWIW, in my humble opinion, etc, applying a license-like model against a piece of data like this is tantamount to extortion...

Comment: Disagree about the "license" comparison.  When you buy a cert you get a piece of data.  But the cert issuer has to maintain infrastructure to verify the cert when someone hits your site.  There is ongoing expense, and the renewals support that.

Comment: the cert issuer only has to provide infrastructure if they're offering online revocation (e.g. OCSP).  *Normal* validation requires no such infrastructure - all of the required information is within the cert.

Comment: And if a CA is not providing revocation checking (preferably OCSP) you shouldn't really be buying anything from them... Those things are there for a reason -- to make it possible to revoke compromised certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Your server certificate hostname has to match what the client expects it to be. If your server certificate says site1.mysite.com and the client tries to dereference site2.mysite.com, the client will report a problem even if DNS directs that to site1.mysite.com.